# How to reflect the matrix Y = WX

Tags: matrices, reflection

I'm trying to reflect this matrix in order to find a value in X.

$Y=WX$ means $y' = w_0, + w_1 * x$

And I would like to find the vector form for $ x' = \frac{y -w_0}{w_1}$

I'm trying with $X = YW^{−1}$

but when I do this in numpy with the following code:

```
x_p = np.linalg.inv(W) @ [1, 45.0]
```

I got this error.

> LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional

I'm assuming I'm not doing well the reflect for that matrix. Can you guys help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use the rotation matrix

Comment: Rotation matrix is given by \begin{bmatrix} cosx&-sinx\\sinx&cosx \end{bmatrix}